# Why are this function's second partial derivatives not continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

so we know that for a function's mixed partial derivatives to be symmetrical we need their second partial derivatives to be continuous. In this example
f(x,y) =
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \dfrac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & \quad \text{for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{for $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
  \end{array}
they $Fxy$ and $Fyx$ are not the same in $(0,0)$, but I'm not so sure how to prove their second derivatives are not continous in that point, how would I go about it?

Comment: Consider, for example, the one-variable functions $g(x) = f(x,x)$ and $h(x)=f(x,2x)$.

Comment: Essentially the idea, which might be useful for other problems as well, is to study the restriction of the multivariable function to lines.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

We have:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,y)=-\frac{4xy^3(x^2-3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}
$$

now take the limit $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on the paths $y=x$ and $y=-x$

Comment: And I can just do that? Just replace $y=x$ and $y=-x$?

Comment: Yes. This proof that for two different paths the limits are different and the limit for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$  is path-dependent ( so it doe not exists.