# Second Derivatives Continuous but Mixed Partials not Equal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm working on the following problem:

> Consider the $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$ for everywhere outside the origin and $f(0,0)=0$ at the origin is. Show that the second derivative of $f$ exists but the mixed partials are not equal at the origin.

My work:

I'm getting for $\nabla f = <\frac{yx^4+4x^2y^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2},\frac{x^5-4x^3y^2-xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}>$. My analysis show that the partials are continuous at zero and take the value $0$ at the origin. I'm having trouble analyzing the second derivative:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-4xy^3(x^2-3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}&\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\\\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}&\frac{4yx^3(y^2-3x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\lim_{\|h\|\rightarrow 0} \frac{\nabla f((0,0)+h)-\nabla f((0,0))- A \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} \\ = \lim_{\|h\|\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\nabla f(h)-\langle f_{xx}h_x+f_{xy}h_y,f_{yx}h_x+f_{yy}h_y\rangle\|}{\|h\|} \\= \lim_{\|h\|\rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\nabla f(h)-\langle\frac{-4xy^3(x^2-3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}h_x+\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}h_y,\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}h_x+\frac{4yx^3(y^2-3x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}h_y\rangle\|}{\|h\|}$$

When I do a polar conversion on this thing and send $r \rightarrow 0$ (uniform for all $\theta$), I get all my $r$'s canceling out -- leaving a limit dependent on theta. But according to the problem, this ratio should go to zero though. Does anyone know what's going on?

I've seen other problems [like](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324890/why-are-this-functions-second-partial-derivatives-not-continuous) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219759/show-that-both-mixed-partial-derivatives-exist-at-the-origin-but-are-not-equal) that show partials are not continuous at the the origin. That's different though from just establishing *existance* of the total derivative, right?

Comment: You have exactly the same expressions for $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ so if your calculations are correct the mixed partials are equal everywhere, in contradiction of what you are supposed to prove.  How confident are you in your calculations?

Comment: pretty confident, I did them on wolfram alpha. also I think I saw the same expression computed in another question - I would have linked it except I have too many windows open.

Comment: I just did it in sympy and I agree with you.  The mixed partials must be discontinuous though, or they'd be equal.  I guess you have to compute them at the origin from the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that the second derivative exists, all you have to show is that the second partials exist at $(0,0)$.  For example $$
f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}{\frac{f_x(0,y)-f_x(0,0)}{y}}=\lim_{y\to0}{\frac{-y^5}{y^5}}=-1
$$
I also got $$f_{yx}(0,0)=+1,\text{ and }f_{xx}(0,0)=f_{yy}(0,0)=0$$
but I'm getting sleepy, so no guarantees.

**EDIT** $$f_{xx}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f_x(x,0)-f_x(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{x\cdot x^4}=0\\
f_{yy}(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f_y(0,y)-f_y(0,0)}{y-0}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{0}{y\cdot y^4}=0
$$

**EDIT**

To round this off, I verified that the second derivative doesn't exist at the origin, and I might as well share my calculations.  We know that if the derivative exists it must be $$\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$$ so that the linear approximation to $\nabla f(x,y)$ at $(0,0$) will be $\pmatrix{y\\-x}$.  So we need to show that $$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\left\lvert\left\lvert\nabla f(x,y)-(y,-x)^{\top}\right\rvert\right\rvert}{||(x,y)||}
$$ is not equal to $0$.  We will show the limit goes to $\infty$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the curve $x=y^2$.  It suffices to show the numerator goes to $\infty.$  Also, since $||(a,b)||<|a|,$ it is enough to show this for the first component.  Substituting $x=y^2$ we have$$
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y^9+4y^7-y^5}{(y^4+y^2)^2}-y=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2y^7-2y^5}{y^8+2y^6+y^4}=\infty
$$

Comment: Okay -- but don't we need to evaluate the actual ratio as I did to obtain whether the second derivative exists at the origin. Computing the entries in $A$ basically saying, "when the second derivative exists, the value is $A(x,y)$" -- but we haven't established existence yet

Comment: Yes, of course.  I was getting too sleepy when I wrote that.  I should have said that we know what the derivative has to be, so we can just use that  in evaluating the limit of the ratio.  Sorry.

Comment: @saulpatz how did you get $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ to equal $0$. I get that they don't exist. For $f_{xx}$ I obtained this by taking $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_x$

Comment: I added my computations. They use $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f_x(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f_y(x,y)=0$$ which you said you verified.  I haven't checked this.  Are you saying it's incorrect?

Comment: I just confirmed $f_x\to0, f_y\to0\text{ as }(x,y)\to(0,0)$ so I think the calculations are all correct.

Comment: Ah! While I was computing $f_{xx}$, I was computing $f_x(x,y)$, not $f_x(x,0)$ and was obtaining some value that was $y$ dependant. But indeed, $y$ should be set to zero if we are evaluating at zero. Thank you!!